# IOS7 - share video file *.mov to Facebook with dialog

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios7

I want share my short video (*.mov file, stored in Documents directory) to Facebook, with use dialog like in camera roll.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxbo4pcvmcz7hb8/stackoverflow.png (not enough reputation to display image, sorry).

Anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Use UIImagePickerController which will give you the option of 'use'

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIActivityViewController`. below is example how to use it for share an image. If you want to share video, just the `UIImage`. Hope it's help.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSString *caption = @"Text to show";

UIActivityViewController *sharer = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[image, caption] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:sharer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: As far as I know, UIActivityViewController does not work with video files.